# Why the authorize attribute is not getting overridden on action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller which should be only authorized to role= 1 but there is also an action inside it that needs to be authorized to both roles i.e. 1 and 2 so what I did is that I have authorized the controller to role 1 and then overridden the action to have 2 roles but that doesn't work, it's still only accessible to role 1.

why ?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "1")]
public class ServicesController : BaseController
{
    // GET: Services
    [OverrideAuthorization]
    [Authorize(Roles="1,2")]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetServices()
    {
        return Json(ServicesRepository.SelectServices(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's that `OverrideAuthorization` you have there?

Comment: Probably have to do this the opposite way, make the controller accessible to "1,2" and all but this action only accessible to "1"

Comment: @TJWolschon that would make it accessible to role 2 overall. Role 2 just needs to access 1 action

Comment: Yeah, that's why you would then restrict it on a per-action basis. The way I'm seeing it right now is it trys to authorize at the controller and can't, but it won't go further down to check the action method, so you'd have to let it get past that first auth.

Comment: @Stacky please add source code of `BaseController` to your example

Comment: Your code is correct.  How are you testing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. I guess you need to override another action too because it seems like you are not overriding the action that returns the view at first.

Override that action which gets called when you execute the controller.